# How to run something from the folder the script is in

Tags: bash

Lets say I have a script called `foo` in some folder and a script called `bar` in the same folder. Say `foo` looks like this:

```
./bar
```

Now if I call `./foo`, this will work fine, but if I am in another folder and call `somefolder/foo`, it will fail.

How can I get this to the point where `./bar` is interpreted from the directory that `foo` is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` could look like this:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
./bar
```

Comment: The problem is that this will mess up all other arguments that are paths if you change the directory. But combining both statements gives the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Answered pretty exhaustively for bash and other shells in:

[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't answer a question with just a link, please read [how-to-answer]. When you see a question that's an exact duplicate of the earlier question, click on the `flag` button on the question, select `it doesn't belong here` then `exact duplicate` and enter the link to the earlier question. Also leave a comment to let others now (the flag remains invisible until a moderator has acted on it).

Comment: Noted. It may be possible that I did not have enough reputation to flag this - as you can tell I am new.